# Using categories with pages

Tags: categories, pages

I am attempting to use categories for pages (not posts) as a way of filtering child pages.

I am working towards having a 'Work' page that lists all its children, and each of these children will also have categories applied to them. Another sub menu will allow you to choose a category and only those child pages will be listed.

So far:

**functions.php - Show categories meta box for pages**

```
function myplugin_settings() {  
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type('category', 'page');  
}
add_action( 'init', 'myplugin_settings' );
```

**Set up a category menu, which is rendered on my 'work' page**

```
<?php wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' => 'category-menu')); ?>
```

**category.php - Get the ID of the category we're looking at**

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php $cat_id = get_cat_id( single_cat_title("",false) ); ?>

<p>
<?php echo $cat_id; ?>
</p>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

This is where I am stuck: How can I loop though my work child pages that have the category ID that I am getting in my `category.php` template?

I understand that categories aren't really designed for pages so I am open to suggestions as to how to set and filter my pages by some kind of category.

I am already using Advanced Custom Fields so there is scope to use that; I would rather not use any other plugins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have stated, pages aren't meant to have categories. I would rather look into custom post types and taxonomies, but the implementation is still up to you as I don't know your structures

I have never tried this before, neither do I know if this will actually work, but you can try the [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) action to amend the main query to display pages on your `category.php` template

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function ( $query ) {
    if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_category() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'page' ) );
    }
});
```

Comment: Any luck on this issue. Would like to know if this is resolved, and if my solution did not work, please post your solution and accept your own answer :-) Thank you

Comment: Thanks for this - my inexperience with WordPress really shone through here! I ended up creating a custom post type and a custom taxonomy to store my categories.

Comment: No problem, glad something worked out for you. Enjoy :-)